# The range function wont print values

Tags: python

I'm new to python and the `range()` function isn't working. I did the following code:

```
a = input("input ur value")
x = range(0, (len(a)))
for bjk in x:
   print(x)
```

You simply input your value for `a` and it displays numbers `0` through length of `a`. Instead, it repeats the message, `"range(0, len(a)))"` length of a amount of times instead of printing values between 0 and len(a)

Comment: I think you meant: `for bjk in x:   print(bjk)`

Comment: There's no way this code prints "range(0, len(a)))".

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `x`. In your code `x` is `range(0, (len(a)))`. So you are a printing a `range` object. You are iterating using a `bjki` variable so you should printing that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you mean.

```
a = input("input ur value ")
for bjk in range(int(a)):
  print(bjk)
```

Then run

```
input ur value 5
0
1
2
3
4
```